# How to replace two characters at the same time with js?

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is my code.

```
 var str = 'test//123_456';
 var new_str = str .replace(/\//g, '').replace(/_/g, '');
 console.log(new_str);
```

It will print test123456 on the screen.

My question is how to do it in same regular express? not replace string twice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in the regex to match any character in the collection. Although use [repetition](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (`+`, 1 or more) for replacing `//` in a single match.

```
var new_str = str .replace(/[/_]+/g, '');
```

```js
var str = 'test//123_456';
var new_str = str.replace(/[/_]+/g, '');
console.log(new_str);
```

**FYI :** Inside the character class, there is no need to escape the forward slash(in case of [Javascript RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)).

Comment: you do not even need to escape the forward slash in a character class, it improves the readability of the regex

Comment: @PranavCBalan why + :-) ?

Comment: @MartinSchneider but some languages don't accept this behaviour.. ex. php..

Comment: @AvinashRaj : it would replace `//` in a single match .... not sure it makes any change in performance :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj :  check here : https://jsperf.com/regex-rep-replace , which is faster ;)

Comment: yep. I agree with speed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex to match the list of character by using regex character class.

```
var str = "test//123_456";
var nstr = str.replace(/[\/_]/g, '');
```